# Can I inherit a generic class from a generic type T? Like MyClass<T> : T

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, generics, inheritance

What I want to achieve is something like this below, which Visual Studio complains about and I don't know how to achieve it:

```
public abstract class My_BaseControl<T> : T, IRightBasedUsability
        where T : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl 
{

    // Some methods that I want to have for all 
    //the extended asp.net controls along my application
    //which implements IRightBasedUsability

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps c# extension methods are in this case a way to solve your problem.

@see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Eric De Carufel wrote some interesting articles about extension methods and how to manage their scope:
http://blog.decarufel.net/2009/02/extension-methods-series-managing-scope.html

Comment: I like the idea! I will try and let you know ;) Thanks!

Comment: +1 Yup; now that I know pencilCake's intent, that definitely seems like the way to go! I love extension methods; they can sort of enable multiple-inheritance for methods (not properties/fields, though)

Comment: You can't override an abstract method with extension methods.  So, unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 1):

You can't inherit from a non-existent type at all, no; that's what you would be doing with the code you've shown.

The closest you can get would be to inherit from the class in your `where T` clause. The effect would not be much different, anyway.

Comment: Basically T can be Button or CheckBox or DropDown etc. And i want to add a functionality which lets them to be enabled/disabled based on some rightNames provided through properties like: EnabledByRightName, VisibleByRightName.

Comment: Also trying to make sub classes of CheckBox and RadioButton -- can't inherit button base, because then it wouldn't be CheckBox or RadioButton, it would be button base.  Have to write the code twice -- or abstract it out into helper methods, lame.